# Spring boot 2.2.6 trying to find BasicErrorHandler in old way

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, migration

I am trying to update the application from Spring Boot 1.5.11 to 2.2.6. When raising the context, I have the same problem with different dependencies:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

Or

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapperConfigurer' defined in springfox.documentation.spring.web.SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.annotation.SleuthAnnotationAutoConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

etc

I used Dependency Analyzer plugin and I made sure that there are no dependencies on 1.5.11 version.
I understand that the matter is in the Aspects, and that BasicErrorController is now in servlet.error package, but I can not find the place where the old package is used.

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:722)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:227)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.obtainPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:177)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:226)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:289)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:126)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 40 more

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't understand why spring-data-commons-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar trying to use org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController (old way)

Comment: Apparently there is some SPring Data Rest stuff you use that is incompatible (you probably included it yourself instead of using Spring Boot starters).